# How to preserve numbers in a character format for Excel with data.table's fwrite

Tags: r, excel, csv, data.table, fwrite

In the example below, when I save the number in a character format (i.e., .10) as a CSV file using `data.table`'s `fwrite`, Excel displays it as a number rather than a character string.

Is there a way to save the number in a **character** format that Excel can recognize as a string?

I'm **not** simply trying to remove the 0 before the decimal point or keep the trailing 0.

I'd like to keep the character strings **intact**, exactly as they would be displayed in R (e.g., .10 but without the quotation marks).

```
dt <- data.table(a = ".10")
fwrite(dt, "example.csv")

# The saved CSV file opened in Excel shows the number 0.1, rather than the string .10
```

Comment: something along the lines of `fwrite(dt[, lapply(.SD, function(j){paste0('"', j, '"')})], "example.csv", quote=FALSE)` - let me know if that works, I'm not in a position to test ATM. If it does, I'll post it as a formal answer (for you to mark as accepted :D)

Comment: @rg255 Hmm, that didn't work. It could be my Excel issues. Thank you for the comment, though!

Comment: Excel issues? What happens if you open that output in a text editor like notepad/atom

Comment: @rg255 If I open it in notepad, it shows up as ".10" with the quotation marks, which is not exactly the way I wanted. I'm hoping to get it in a format that Excel can recognize the string as a string rather than as a number.

Comment: this is not an R question, it is an excel one.  Suggest to either change it accordingly or delete the question.

Comment: Thank you, I made edits to the question.

Comment: the question is still misleading, This is not an R problem at all.  You should delete the question and ask a new one about importing (correctly formatted)  csv files into excel

Comment: I think it is an R problem to the extent that I am trying to use R to produce a desired output.

Comment: This is not an R problem, it's an Excel problem. If you want Excel output a certain way, then write an xlsx file, not a CSV. It's worth noting that Excel is *not* CSV, and in my opinion, handles CSV files rather poorly.

Comment: Or you can *import* the CSV file into Excel, specifying that column as text.

Comment: @BigBen OK, maybe I'll look into writing an xlsx file instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is mostly brain-dead with regards to reading things in as you want. Here's one workaround:

```r
dat <- data.frame(aschr = c("1", "2.0", "3.00"), asnum = 1:3, hascomma = "a,b", hasnewline = "a\nb", hasquote = 'a"b"')
notnumber <- sapply(dat, function(z) is.character(z) & all(is.na(z) | !grepl("[^-0-9.]", z)))
needsquotes <- sapply(dat, function(z) any(grepl('[,\n"]', z))) & !notnumber
dat[needsquotes] <- lapply(dat[needsquotes], function(z) dQuote(gsub('"', '""', z), FALSE))
dat[notnumber] <- lapply(dat[notnumber], function(z) paste0("=", dQuote(z, FALSE)))
fwrite(dat, "iris.csv", quote = FALSE)
```

Resulting in the following perspective in Excel.

[image: screenshot of Excel's view of the CSV file]

Most of this is precautionary: if you know your data well and you know that none of the data contains commas, quotes, or newlines, then you can do away with the `needsquotes` portions. `notnumber` is the column(s) of interest.

Bottom line, we "trick" excel into keeping it a string by forcing it as an excel formula. This may not work with other spreadsheets (e.g., Calc), I haven't tested.

Comment: As you said, rewriting data as an Excel formula and "tricking" Excel worked really well for me. Thank you for this answer! For the minimal example, `dt[, b:= paste0("=", dQuote(a, FALSE))]` was all it took. I'll have to be careful when data has commas, new lines, commas, etc.

Comment: Yes, the "minimal example" works when all of your data is perfectly compliant, as I said (*"you can do away with the `needsquotes` portions"*). I also generalized it to be one *or more* columns needing protection. The `data.table` methods for doing things did not seem critical to the answer, and in fact if you know `data.table` then modifying base R methods for it is straight-forward; opposite, though, is not true: if one is not familiar with `data.table`-semantics, then translating back to base is not as intuitive. Glad it worked. It's imperfect but certainly a usable hack.